# how to access variables when executing code is finished in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a code that lasts half an hour to be executed completely. But I don't know how to access and see variables after running it. I mean when the program is easy, we can use print() and run the code over and over. But how can I do that without executing it again? I use Pycharm

**Edit:**
something like workspace in matlab.

after a script is finished variables are still accesible.

[image]

Comment: You can't see variables after a script exits, no.

Comment: When your program exits, its memory is reclaimed by the operating system, and all the values of variables that your program contained are erased. You have to print them out, send them to some server, or save them to file *before* your program exits.

Comment: If you're trying to access them in an interactive Python session, you can reorganize your code so that instead of a standalone program, it just exports an entry point function, so you can `import mything` then `mything.dostuff()` inside your interactive interpreter, and then half an hour later you still have the `mything` module with all of its globals. (Or, better, use a class instead of a module.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I know but I expected something like workspace in Matlab

Comment: What sort of variables are these?

Comment: @MartijnPieters An array of numbers and a list of names(string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although a long time have passed since I asked this question(and probably duplicate but I can't find similar ones), let me don't leave it unanswered.

select .py file which is supposed to be executed from top right corner of program window and select "edit configurations"

[image]

then check 'run with python console' enabled.

I don't know which pycharm version added this option to run a code in console for the first time(maybe from its first release!) but that is all should be done!

Answer (score 1):

Run the script in a iterative session, as an example, through ipython.

```
pip install ipython
ipython
run script_name.py
```

After the script execution you will still be able to interact with objects that were created in the script.

Answer (score -1):

You should save your output to a file, e.g:

```
with open("filename", "w+") as file:
    file.write(variable)
```

You'll be able to read it later and store it as a variable, even if you close your session and open it again.

```
with open("filename") as file:
    variable = file.read()
```

No need to run the code again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `variable = file` doesn't do what you want, that's a bit too simple.

Comment: Better? This is how I've used it previously

Comment: It's slightly better, might even work for a single string variable. If only all serialization was so simple... Just in case you are interested: I'm not the one who downvoted, so I can't undownvote it. Imho, it still trivializes the problem. Saving and restoring state of the entire python interpreter should be a little bit more difficult.

Comment: What sort of problems might you run into if you do it like this? The only thing I can think of is the formatting / encoding of the file, but that can be fixed by specifying any encoding when you save. You're right though, this won't save the whole state of the interpreter, just select variables

Comment: That sounds almost like a rhetorical question. What happens usually if you take a pile of complicated information and convert it to human readable string, and then try to read it by a machine again? Nothing good happens, that's for sure. If you change the encoding... well yeah, then you obtain something between JSON and Protobuf, sooner or later.